# Term for someone/thing that is viewed strikingly differently by different people

Tags: single-word-requests, american-english

For example, Person X is viewed as a hero by Group X but a villain by Group Y. What would Person X then be called?

Comment: ***Divisive***, ***Contentious***.

Comment: Also: **Controversial**.

Comment: That person is Deadpool

Comment: Hank, what's a "deadpool"? Love the word but have never encountered it before.

Comment: @MarkHubbard, Deadpool is a comic book character who embodies the characteristic described in my question

Comment: @NajmSheikh - Thank you for the additional information!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**"polemical"** or **"controversial"** seem like good fits.

> - **polemical**  - engaged in or addicted to [**polemics**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/polemics). -  (the art or practice of disputation or controversy —usually used in plural but singular or plural in construction)
> - A **controversial figure** is one who arouses [**controversy**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/controversy). -  ("a discussion marked especially by the expression of opposing views.")

Comment: "Controversial" is a good description of someone based on others' views of them. "Polemical" has to do, not with how the person is viewed, but on his or her own actions.

Comment: I ended up using contentious but controversial is a good pick as well.

Answer (score 1):

[**polarizer**](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/polarizer) or polariser
Noun
a person or a device that causes polarization

[**polarization**](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/polarization#polarization__2) in American English)
noun
1.
2.  the process or condition of being divided into two opposing groups

[**polarize**](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/polarize)
Word forms: polarizes, **polarizing**, polarized
REGIONAL NOTE:  in BRIT, also use polarise
transitive verb/intransitive verb
If something polarizes people or if something polarizes, two separate groups are formed with opposite opinions or positions.
(all from *Collins Dictionary*)

Examples (mine) that might work in your context:

“He.she/it is a polarizer.”

“He/she/it is polarizing the nation”

“He/she/[it] is a polarizing figure/force/[issue].”

Comment: Yes! You nailed it and did so without mentioning the name of the person you might have had in mind!